# Supervised classification using tree methods

Tags: classification, supervised-learning

What work has been done for supervised classification using tree methods that utilize linear combinations of variables instead of single variables?

Answer (score 1):

There are quiet a few papers which delve around that idea. Basically it consists of taking a max-margin classifier that divide the feature space recursively according to some criteria, until a desired accuracy/performance is achieved.

It is a combinatorial problem, and different papers offer different heuristic to tackle complexity in an efficient way.

One work is [Margin Trees for High-dimensional Classification](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/margintree.pdf), which describes a basic classifier used to build up a binary tree. There are a number of approaches (which in spirit are quite similar to this one) using SVMs, like for example [A Hierarchy of Support Vector Machines for Pattern Detection](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume7/sahbi06a/sahbi06a.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

There is an R package called [oblique.tree](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/oblique.tree/index.html) which splits on linear combinations of variables. Also, another R package called [obliqueRF](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/obliqueRF/index.html) which expands this to forests.